# Multiple dropdown menu , submenu was disappears

Tags: html, css

**I have a navigation menu with three levels, but can't access the last one**. If you see example here : "Products" => under this are two more menu-levels i.e `item1`, `item2`, `item3`. If you move over on `item3` again I need to display submenus related to the `item3` menu. Click there and see if user mouse over on item-3 after displaying `item-3.1`, `item-3.2`, `item-3.3`. When trying to hover to the level-three menu of "Products", it suddenly disappears.

**HTML & CSS code example below:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dropdown</title>
<style>
#nav-main li a.nav-link {
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    padding-top: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

#nav-main a.nav-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sub-menu-panel {
    display: none;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-top: 3px solid #212121;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
    margin-top: -3px;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.dropdown-menu a{background-color:#cfcfcf;padding:10px;}
ul li.sub-menu:hover div.sub-menu-pannel{display:grid;}
ul.nav > li.dropdown:hover > div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;}
li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;position: absolute;left: -159px;top: 53px;;}
li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > a.dropdown + div.dropdown-menu > a.dropdown:hover + div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <nav role="navigation" id="nav-main" class="okayNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav " style="display:flex;">
              <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
              <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#features">Employee Login</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown sub-menu active">
                <a alt="Sencillo" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" href="#" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-hover="dropdown">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-panel">
                  <a href="#">item-1</a>
                  <a href="#">item-2</a>
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-3</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a href="#">item-31</a>
                    <a href="#">item-32</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown">item-33</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#">item-33-1</a>
                        <a href="#">item-33-2</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li><a alt="Sencillo" class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#leave-message">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you style `:hover` element, it will work only when element is hovered by cursor. So, when you hover `a.dropdown` `div.dropdown-menu` next to it appears, but when you move it away from `a.dropdown` to `div.dropdown-menu` itself, `:hover` effect disappears, making div disappear too. To solve this problem you need to put `.dropdown-menu` inside of `.dropdown` element and use `.dropdown .dropdown-menu` instead of `.dropdown + .dropdown-menu`. In this case when you move cursor to `.dropdown-menu` element, `:hover` effect will remain, because hovering child element means hovering parent too.

I suggest you to change structure to

```
                <div class="dropdown-menu sub-menu-panel">
                  <a href="#">item-1</a>
                  <a href="#">item-2</a>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">item-3</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a href="#">item-31</a>
                    <a href="#">item-32</a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#">item-33</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#">item-33-1</a>
                        <a href="#">item-33-2</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and change css part to

```
li.sub-menu .sub-menu-panel > .dropdown:hover > div.dropdown-menu{display: grid;position: absolute;left: -159px;top: 53px;;}
```

Comment: thank you so munch  for helping me .. it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Drop down
<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Tab 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tab 21</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e) {
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

you can actually try this out and implement it..